# the final page 20% trance Y one page Pure JS One Page Scroll Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm using https://github.com/peachananr/purejs-onepage-scroll 
i want final page 20% transform

 example http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-One-Page-Scroll-Plugin-For-jQuery-SONP/

```html
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper"> 
   <div class="main">
     
      <section class="page1">
        <div class="page_container">
    
       </div>
      </section>
     
     <section class="page2">
       <div class="page_container">
      
       </div>
      </section>
     
     <section class="page3"><!-- i want 20% transform  -->
       <div class="page_container">
          
         </div>
       </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "final page 20% transform 
example"?

Comment: …and "20% trance Y"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the documentation on how to ask a question at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i using http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html